# How do i play iTunes music from my PC via bluetooth to an external speaker like i can from Google Music?

Tags: itunes, bluetooth

I have a wireless remote speaker that i use to play online music to from my PC running windows 10.  I want to do the same with my iTunes music. The connection from PC to speaker is via bluetooth.

Comment: The bluetooth speaker connects to the computer and becomes the audio output device. It does not matter what generates the sound (iTunes Youtube, googleplay or whatever). Once connected, the speaker acts as the computer speaker.

Comment: So all you want to do is sit at your computer which has a bluetooth speaker attached and play iTunes music from your PC to the speaker?

Comment: Hi Carl,  that is exactly what i would expect too. But, it is not the case.  I will have the online music playing via BT through the remote speaker, pause it, and start a tune in iTunes and it just plays out the laptop speakers.

Comment: @johnpw I ran into this, quitting and restarting iTunes *after* pairing the speaker worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little bit late, but in case you still haven't figured it out you can open the sound control panel, then the playback tab, and click on your speaker (once it's connected) and click set default. If you don't want to use your speaker anymore just set your PC's speaker back to default. Hope I helped!

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. It working after changing one setting on the Itunes app.  Go to "Edit".  Then "Preferences".  Change the "Play Audio Using" setting to "Direct Sound".  Restart Itunes and it should connect.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, new answer. Even when it correctly appears as a device, don't forget to go the bluetooth menu in OS X and choose 'set up new device'. Once you've set it up , any bluetooth speaker or any device will work just fine. Skipping the set-up step might just show the speaker in the menu with an option to use it which doesn't trigger the speakers. So.. be sure to do this well :)

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem. Doing a bit of research, it feels as if Apple wants to keep you locked up in Appleland and use AirPlay. My fix (which has only worked once - but still okay 24 hours later) was to select Apple TV in iTunes and then de-select it. Sound instantly moved from Windows Surface speakers to bluetooth speakers. Maybe an answer ...?